# LineNumberReader to support UTF-8 encoding

Tags: utf-8, java-io

When I am trying to read text from the file, the underlying text is not appearing correctly using `LineNumberReader`

**The text trying to read from file -**

```
¥ · £ · € · $ · ¢ · ₡ · ₢ · ₣ · ₤ · ₥ · ₦ · ₧ · ₨ · ₩ · ₪ · ₫ · ₭ · ₮ · ₯ · ₹
```

**Sample Code--**

```
FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\JavaUser4\\Desktop\\checkImort.txt");
        InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(fis, "UTF-8");
        LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(streamReader);
        String sLine = reader.readLine();
        System.out.println(sLine);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
```

Output -

```
? ? ? ? ? ? $ ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ? ?
```

Please help to read this text correctly using `LineNumberReader`. I prefer to stay on `LineNumberReader` because I was using `RandomAccessFile` that was a perfect solution according to my requirement

- Open a file containing UTF-8 encoded text.
- Set Line Number from which we need to start reading a file.
- Read 25 lines from text file.
- Get last position of offset.
- Exit.
- Again open a file.
- Set Line Number from where we need to start reading next 25 lines from the same file.
- Read 25 lines from text file.
- Get last offset.
- And so on.

Drawback was `RandomAccessFile` was not supporting UTF-8 encoding and I moved to `LineNumberReader` but same is happening here. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're doing the reading correctly (assuming the file is actually in UTF-8 encoding).

The problem is with the output.

The output stream you're writing to is probably configured to output as ISO-8859-1 or one of its variants (I guess you're running this on Windows, as this is a common problem on Windows).

Note that the output "?" is often caused by the fact that *some character* can't be represented in a given encoding. So your `String` contains the correct characters (you should be able to check that in a debugger), but the output stream can't write that.